# Imacro script for dynamic link

Tags: imacros

is there anyway to make imacro to click this link ? it's dynamic link. so everytime "id=33" will be change.

```html
<span itemprop="name">
<h2><a href="/story.php?id=33">link</a></h2>
</span>
```

Preview = http://elakirihub.xyz/new.php

Thanks

Comment: Props for adding the preview. Please be sure to mark my answer and upvote if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use * character as a wildcard when the last part of the link changes.

Working Example for your case:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/story.php?id=*
```

---

Since you did not state the environment my example is for iMacros Browser plugin, but the fundamentals apply for iMacros in general.
If you are unsure how to generate the full code before the addition of wildcards you can experiment with recordings or go to the iMacros wiki:
wiki.imacros.net/